# Can the encryption Keys stored in the Android's KeyStore be backed up?

Tags: android, backup, keystore, restore

When you encrypt the app's data stored on the device, it is recommended to use the `KeyStore` to generate and save the key Material used for the encryption.
If the user wants to backup the app's internal storage, he can use adb backup or `Google's Cloud Backup`. That's what I have understood.

But when the data is encrypted by keys stored in the `Android's KeyStore`, is it possible to restore the backup the user/Google made?
Or does the the use of encryption prevent the backup function?

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34765340/can-androids-keystore-be-backed-up/38356800#38356800

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Android's keystore be backed up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34765340/can-androids-keystore-be-backed-up)

Answer (score 0):

It will not work. This is very sad that Google force two things that don't work together. Keystore on Android doesn't have a backup option like Keychain on iOS.
Your data will be backed up but after restoration, you will not have an option to decrypt it.

You should use a different way to backup data - the easiest one is to have user's account and store his data on your backend.

I wrote about it more here:
https://medium.com/@thecodeside/android-auto-backup-keystore-encryption-broken-heart-love-story-8277c8b10505